# AngularJS - How can I get data from GET method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My Controller:

```
angular.module('apartmentCtrl', [])

.controller('ApartmentController', function ($scope, $http, Apartment) {
    $scope.loading = true;

    $scope.myLocation = '';

    Apartment.get($scope.myLocation).success(function (data) {
        $scope.apartments = data;
        $scope.loading = false;
    });
});
```

My Service
angular.module('apartmentService', [])

```
.factory('Apartment', function ($http) {
    return {
        get: function (myLocation) {
            //return $http.get('/api/apartments');
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/api/apartments',
                //headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                params: {location: myLocation}
            });
        }
    };
});
```

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="myLocation" class="form-control" ng-model="myLocation">
```

How can I get data from GET method by AngularJS and pass it to `params`

Comment: Please show your code. Are you using Angular to submit the form?

Comment: You can use `$http` to do that.

http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_http.asp

Comment: you have to use `$http` service in your controller. please show your code

Comment: No. I submit the form in a general way.

Comment: I don't understand the question, are you trying to take what was typed into your html form and use those values as the params in the GET method you showed above?

Comment: @NicholasSmith yes :D

Comment: Can you show your complete html for your form, and the button that triggers submission.  If you have an actual form with submit button, you'll need to add your function as `ng-submit` on the form.  Otherwise you'll need to add your function to whatever button you have created.  See my answer for example of ng-submit to capture standard form behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass some value from your form as "location", you should bind it to your model, and explicitly pass it to your factory get function.

I have a working example here, it just does a window alert showing you the typed in data, in place of the $http call, but the idea is the same.

http://plnkr.co/edit/fRra6RfQrSZb8rzrm4XF?p=preview

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>

    <form ng-submit="getIt()">
      <input type="text" ng-model="myLocation"/>
      <input type="submit"/>
    </form>

  </body>

</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Apartment) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.myLocation = 'Hollywood';

  $scope.getIt = function() {
    Apartment.get($scope.myLocation);
  }
});

app.factory('Apartment', function ($window) {
        return {
            get: function (whatLocation) {
                $window.alert(whatLocation);
            }
        };
    });
```

Comment: I can not get the value of `myLocation` :(

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But I have a new problem. Assume I have a url like: `http://myproject.com/apartments?location=&arrival=1/15/2015&departure=2/1/2015&room=1`. How can I get the parameters `arrival`, `departure`, `room` and attach them to data of form when I submit.

Comment: Exactly the same, pass all the parameters you need, and in your $http add them to your parameters you are sending.  So your Apartments GET function might look like: `get: function (myLocation, arrival, departure, room)...` and in that method you'd call to your web service with: `params: {location: myLocation, arrival: arrival, departure: departure, rooms: rooms}`

Comment: I don't understand. Sorry, I'm newbie in AngularJS. How can I pass all parameters in url to `params` when the page was loaded.

Comment: You can read the request URL paramters using $location.search().  Please see example of your code: http://pastebin.com/RVFeJbt3

Comment: I read the document at: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

But when I use this url: http://myproject.com/apartments?location=123&arrival=123

I can not get `location` and `arrival` value by using your code.

Comment: This url: myproject.com/apartments?location=123&arrival=123 is it part of your angular application or some server-side application?

Comment: it is part of my application.